# Is this a well-defined set?

Tags: probability, set-theory, definition

Let $A$ be some arbitrary finite set. (e.g. $\{a,b\}$).

Now let $$S=(A\times B)^n$$
Where $B$ is the set of all possible probability functions on $S$:

$$B=\left\{p\in S\to\mathbb R^+:\int_S p(s)ds=1\right\}$$

This definition of $S$ has a kind of "self-referential" structure. Things tend to go wrong when we introduce self-reference in mathematics, so my question is: **Is this a well-defined set? If it is not a set, is it even a well-defined class? Is there any way to make sense of this (e.g. using measure theory), or is it nonsensical?**

Note that this definition is inspired by Aumann's concept of an interactive belief system, where $n$ agents have a probability distribution over the set $A$, but also over each other's probability distributions over this set, and over THESE probability distributions, ad infinitum.

Comment: No, this definition is incorrect. In the usual formalization of set theory, no $S $ satisfies it, and I doubt anyone interested in these matters would consider appropriate the contortions required to reach a background theory where there is a unique object satisfying the definition. Perhaps it is better to define $S $ as the limit of a (maybe transfinite) sequence of approximations.

Comment: I would prefer a simpler example. It seems to me that yours runs down to some sort of equation.

Comment: BTW Is $f \in A\to B$ a common notation? I remember only $f\in B^A$.

Comment: @mvw . The usual notation is $f\in B^A$ or $f\in ^{A}B.$ The latter is seen in set-theory when $ A$ and $B$ are cardinal  ordinals,  as $A^B$ may  denote the cardinal of $^AB$.

Comment: Supplemental to the comment by Andres E. Caicedo . The existence of $S$ as defined will violate the axiom of Foundation (Regularity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a legitimate definition of a set. What you have written down is a sort of "set equation;" there are three possible behaviors of such an object:

- **There are multiple solutions**. "$X=X$" is a trivial example; "$X=X\cup\{\mathcal{P}(x): x\in X\}$" is a slightly less trivial example (proving that there is an $X$ satisfying it requires the axiom (scheme) of Replacement). In this case there may still be a "*distinguished*" solution - e.g. the least fixed point of a positive inductive definition - but the equation cannot be said to define a set without further elaboration.
- **There are no solutions**. The most obvious example is "$X=\{x: x\not\in X\}$." In this case there's nothing to be done. At least in [the usual axioms of set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), your proposed definition is of this type, the reason being that elements of the transitive closure of $S$ would have higher "rank" than $S$ itself *(basically, this is a more general version of the problem of sets containing themselves being ruled out by the axiom of regularity; it breaks into two pieces, [showing that every set has a rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512610/how-to-prove-any-set-belong-to-a-v-alpha-in-cumulative-hierarchy) and [showing that rank is "$\in$-increasing"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569812/how-to-prove-rank-function-is-monotone-in-cumulative-hierarchy))*.
- **There is a unqiue solution**. This is the case in which it's at least somewhat reasonable to say that the equation "defines" a set. However, I would *still* consider this incorrect: rather, if $E$ is such an equation then "the unique solution to $E$" is a definition of a set (and it still requires a *proof* to be legitimate: we need to show that indeed $E$ has a unique solution). As an example of a nontrivial such equation, consider $$X=\{x: x\in X\iff x\not\in X\}.$$ It's a good exercise to check that this equation has exactly one solution, namely $X=\emptyset$.

See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798390/can-definitions-of-operators-and-relations-lead-to-contradictions/2798407#2798407).